# Was this patent granted?

Tags: granted

In reference to the patent: [US20030042366](https://www.google.com/patents/US20030042366)

Was this patent granted??

Answer (score 0):

This patent application was abandoned. Additionally, there are no other patent applications stemming from this one in the US patent office. So, no patent was granted.